# How is scroll height larger than window height?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a function stop running before the user scrolls the entire window height, but what I am seeing in the console isn't adding up. Somehow, the scrollHeight (which is the scrollTop value) ends up being more than the window heigh itself. How is this possible?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    if( $(window).width() > 720  && $(window).scrollTop() < (windowHeight-400) ) {

                $(window).bind('scroll', function(){

                var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
                console.log('scroll height', scrollHeight)
                console.log('window height', windowHeight)

                function parallaxScroll(){
                   $('#main').css('top',(500-(scrollHeight*2))+'px');
                };

                    parallaxScroll();
                });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/height/#height), you are getting the height of the viewport, meaning that you are only getting what's in view. You need to set the height to the document height like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var windowHeight = $(document).height();

    if( $(window).width() > 720  && $(window).scrollTop() < (windowHeight-400) ) {

                $(window).bind('scroll', function(){

                var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
                console.log('scroll height', scrollHeight)
                console.log('window height', windowHeight)

                function parallaxScroll(){
                   $('#main').css('top',(500-(scrollHeight*2))+'px');
                };

                    parallaxScroll();
                });
    }
});
```